# gcc mingw gives garbage output when combining with assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, mingw, calling-convention

My gcc:Thread model: posix

gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

I'm trying to create a simple application which sums two numbers with two files saberi.c and saberi.s using gcc and intel syntax where saberi means sum.

saberi.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int saberi(int a, int b);
int main()
{   
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("Sum is: %d\n", saberi(a, b));
    return 0;
}
```

saberi.s

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text
    .globl saberi
saberi:
    enter 0,0
    mov eax, edi
    add eax, esi
    leave
    ret
```

I then do gcc saberi.c saberi.s and when I open the executable and type any two numbers for example(1 and 2) and I get a random value as the sum.

Comment: it certainly compiles fine on my system with gcc (7.3.0, not mingw).  So, it has something to do with the compiler in your mingw I guess.  Maybe you need to declare the function **extern** or use **register** with the arguments or something?  I haven't done any assembly code in so long that I'm really just guessing...

Comment: @BobShaffer Tried using both extern and register didn't change anything, thanks though.

Comment: Because your MinGW toolchain is generating native windows code. The native [Windows 64-bit calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention) passes the first 2 parameters via RCX and RDX (Which differs from the 64-bit System V ABI used by Linux which is uses RDI and RSI). Try   `mov eax, ecx`
    `add eax, edx`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MinGW compiler compiles by default for the Windows target. Meaning the compiler follows the [Windows ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) and windows calling convention. 
The first two integer arguments are passed in `rcx` and `rdx` instead of `rdi` and `rsi` as in the System V ABI.

You can verify by generating the assembly for saberi.c as -

```
gcc -S saberi.c -o saberi_compiled.s
```

You will see that before calling `saberi`, the compiler moves the arguments in `ecx` and `edx`.

So your saberi.s should be changed to -

```
intel_syntax noprefix
.text
    .globl saberi
saberi:
    enter 0,0
    mov eax, ecx
    add eax, edx
    leave
    ret
```

And you should get correct results.

The other option is to tell the compiler to use the System V ABI while calling `saberi`. This can be done in gcc (MinGW) using `sysv_abi` attribute for the `saberi` function as -

```
int saberi(int a, int b) __attribute__((sysv_abi));
```

Then you can keep your assembly the same. This method is useful when you want to write assembly that is portable across platforms. But of course it is limited to only `gcc`.